# Is is ok to refer to object owned by root aggregate directly in this case?

Tags: object-oriented, domain-driven-design

While I'm trying to design classes based on DDD principles, I'm quite confused for this particular "pattern".  For example, `ScholarshipProgram` contains many `Cycle`. They seem to be aggregate to me.  But `Student` only apply to a `Cycle` not the `ScholarshipProgram`.  Should I design it to be like this:

[image]

This seems to break aggregation principle in DDD.  If I'm to follow DDD, I could design it to be something like:

[image]

But while this following DDD principles, but feel it is a bit unnatural. Where should I put the method to manages `Cycle` for a certain `ScholarshipProgram` such as creating a new cycle, duplicating existing cycle, getting last cycle for a program, etc.

What is the suitable of design to solve this kind of "pattern" that is still compatible with DDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Cycle` belongs to a particular `ScholarshipProgram` only, then it should belong to the `ScholarshipProgram` aggregate. If a `Cycle` can be part of two or more `ScholarshipProgram`, `Cycle` should be its own aggregate root.

In any case the aggregate root is your entry point. In the first case that means that `ScholarshipProgram` would have the methods to manage `Cycle`s such as `createCycle(StudentProfile, ..)` and `duplicateCycle(cycleIdentifier)`. These methods take care of the internal data structures, which might contain a collection of `Cycle`s.

Comment: `Cycle` belongs to a particular `ScholarshipProgram` only.  But `StudentProfile` subscribed to a particular `Cycle` not `ScholarshipProgram`. If `ScholarshipProgram` is the root then `StudentProfile` can't refer to that particular `Cycle`, right?

Comment: `StudentProfile` can get `Cycle` objects for reading, not for modification. To modify a `Cycle`, `ScholarshipProgram` should have the appropriate methods.

Comment: Alternatively, even though `Cycle` belongs to a particular `ScholarshipProgram` only, you might feel more comfortable to make `Cycle` its own aggregate root. Small aggregates are recommended here: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/. The important thing to note is that every aggreate is a transaction boundary, meaning that usually you would not commit changes to different aggregates within the same transaction.

Comment: Would you like to add reference for this part "`StudentProfile` can get `Cycle` objects for reading, not for modification"?  I used to think this is breaking Law of Demeter even only for reading since `Cycle` is *inside* of `StudentProfile`

Comment: The point is that the properties of `Cycle` are probably part of the public conceptual model, so there is little reason to hide them. See Eric Evan's answer in this thread called [DDD and Demeter law](http://domaindrivendesign.yahoogroups.narkive.com/wxOLxBFx/ddd-and-demeter-law). Looking at it from a slightly different angle, the [chapter on aggregates in Implementing DDD](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=8) talks about using the law of Demeter and Tell, Don't Ask: State modifying operations belong to the aggregate, properties are accessible from clients.